# Understanding DirectX and OpenGL

Tags: opengl, 3d, directx

I don't exactly get the concept. Are they a set of api's to a library that accesses the hardware. If so is it possible for someone to create a brand new api like opengl and directx?

Comment: You should read this post: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/88055 and maybe this one: http://blog.wolfire.com/2010/01/Why-you-should-use-OpenGL-and-not-DirectX:)

Comment: And [this series of blog posts by Ryg](http://fgiesen.wordpress.com/category/graphics-pipeline/page/2/) is also very informative.

Comment: @SamuelGosselin: And yet, neither one of those actually *answers his question*. He's asking about the relationship between the APIs and the hardware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of graphics API like OpenGL or DirectX is to provide a single graphics API to use across a wide range of hardware. In fact, a large portion of these APIs are actually implemented in the graphics drivers. If you were to design your own graphics API you would either have to make it run on almost entirely on the CPU ("in software") or to write special code for each type of graphics card you wanted to support.